# How to pass scala List or Array inside if condition?

Tags: arrays, scala, list

I have put a check inside a method in scala like this.

```
def run(beamServices: BeamServices): Unit = {
   if ((beamServices.strategy.planSelectorForRemoval.equals("Check with list of strings")) && (!beamServices.modeChoiceClass.equals("ModeChoiceLCCM"))) {
       logger.error("Simulation breaks")            
   }
}
```

The above check is just for single `String` but I have to check with around 10 `Strings`. It would be very tedious and lengthy code if I put 10 checks here like above. So what I decided that instead of writing 10 checks individually , let I create a List or `Arrray` of Strings like this.

```
val listOfString = Array{"String1","String2","String3"....."String10"}
```

and tried to implement the `List` in condition like this.

```
def run(beamServices: BeamServices): Unit = {
  if ((beamServices.strategy.planSelectorForRemoval.equals(listOfString.foreach(x => x))) && (!beamServices.modeChoiceClass.equals("ModeChoiceLCCM"))) {
     logger.error("Simulation breaks")            
   }
}
```

I know the above implementation is wrong. I just written it to give you an idea what I mean to say.
Please suggest me with some classic solutions

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including input and expected output. Also, try replacing the classes in your program with classes of the standard library or provide minimal implementations of they so anybody can copy & paste your code to test it - BTW, I think what you want is to check if a single value is present in a collection of values, am I correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by "list of classes"? Scala types? Java classes? Objects of type `Class[_]`? Some stringly-typed constants from a classification task? What is `Array{...}` supposed to be? It's not valid Scala syntax. This question is unclear.

Comment: That code with the if condition looks to me like Java in disguise! Why would you do it this way? Read about pattern matching with boundary conditions and try to re-write your code. This what you have is just some ugly piece of Java!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes you get it write. Also i didn't put actual classes because there names are too lengthy thats why i just put a sample here.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Just ignore the list of classes. I am just asking how to put a List of String in if condition .

Comment: @Ayush in that case Dima's answer is enough. You can just call the [`contains` _method_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean) on **List** to check if your value is equals to any of the values of the collection _(**Array** has the same method)_. In any case a **Set** makes more sense, because it can only have unique elements and it has constant check time - with a **Set** you can also use `contains` or the [`apply` _method_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html#apply(elem:A):Boolean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing, that what you are trying to ask is how to check if a given string matches one of several other strings.

If that's the case, the answer would be to use `Set`:

```
val stringsToMatch = Set("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
if (!stringsToMatch(beamServices.modelChoice)) { doStuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val listOfClasses = List("ClassA","ClassB","ClassC"....."ClassJ"}

def run(beamServices: BeamServices): Unit = {
   if ((beamServices.strategy.planSelectorForRemoval.equals("check with 10 classes")) && (!listOfCLasses.contains(beamServices.modeChoiceClass))) {
       logger.error("Simulation breaks")            
   }
}
```